# How to add item in array using nested for each loop in php

Tags: php, arrays, oracle-call-interface

I am trying to create array of row object from table in PHP.  I am using the below code to do it, but I am not getting the expected result.

I want the below format:

```
[{"fName":"apple","fprice":11,"quantity":2},{"dName":"orange","fprice":31,"quantity":6}]
```

But using the following code I am getting only the last row last column value:

```
$query = 'select fname,fprice,imgpath,fdesc,cid from food_data';
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
oci_execute($stid, OCI_DEFAULT);
while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($stid)) {
    foreach ($row as $key=>$val) {
        //echo $item." <br />";
        $data = array(
            array(''.$key.''=>''.$val.'') );
    }
    //echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: use `array_push()` during `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just fetch into an appended element `[]` of the array.  All of the columns from the `SELECT` will be there:

```
while($data[] = oci_fetch_assoc($stid));
```

Even easier to use [oci_fetch_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-all.php):

```
oci_fetch_all($stid, $data, null, null, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW);
```

In both cases `$data` will be an array of rows that are arrays of column names and column data.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = 'select fname,fprice,imgpath,fdesc,cid from food_data';
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
oci_execute($stid, OCI_DEFAULT);
$res = array();
while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($stid)) {
    $res[] = $row;
}
```

After that `$res` will contain what you want.

Comment: I'm glad it's helpful. you may mark the answer as correct ;)